# Widget background color in system color?

Tags: gtk, pygtk

how can I set the color of a widget(VBox in particular) to the same color as are default dialogs on Windows? It seems to work properly automatically on Linux, but on Windows the widget is a different shade of gray. 
It is placed as a custom widget to GtkPrintOperation, and it looks awful because of the color

Answer (score -1):

GtkBox doesn't have any window, GtkBox is just a container that arranges the widgets inside, for you to change the background of a widget has to check first if the widget is using his own window, and then go through it. Here you should look at [this](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-drawing-model.html).
Besides that, after you are clear of what you want, there's a bunch of samples around google.